# If we accelerate a neutron star to move at speeds comparable to light would it become a blackhole because of the added energy?

Tags: black-hole, neutron-star

Could a neutron star turn into a blackhole if it is accelerated to near luminal velocities? And if it slows down after a while, does it become a neutron star again?

Comment: No, if an object is a black hole in any inertial frame then it's a black hole in every inertial frame. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/123208 and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32578/16685

Comment: OTOH, if your speeding neutron star crashes into another body, then you will get a black hole if the total energy density (to be more precise, the [stress-energy-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)) in the region is high enough, in other words, if the combined mass & kinetic energy is high enough.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512636/123208 BTW, some neutron stars are traveling quite fast relative to their galactic neighbours, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGR_J11014%E2%88%926103 but the speed is less than 1% of light speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring ...what can happen in neutron star binaries if they finally collide.

Comment: @peterh Depending on the mass & KE, you may get a larger neutron star, or a black hole. In either case, the collisions is likely to create (and eject) some heavy elements via the r-process, eg gold. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star_merger and the periodic table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleosynthesis#Timeline and https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04138

Answer (score 1):

In special relativity, changes of reference frame are symmetric between observer and observee.  If moving a neutron star gave it enough kinetic energy to become a black hole, then you could effect this change by jumping into a moving reference frame yourself.

What matters is the neutron star's mass in its rest frame.